# how to skip typescript's noImplicitAny=true rule on node modules packages?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, typescript2.0, webpack-2

I'm building angular 2 app using Typescript 2 and Webpack 2. As a loader I use awesome-typescript-loader. I set noImplicitAny = true in tsconfig.json. But some of npm packages I used implicitly has an 'any' type. (e.g. angular2-platform-node). So I want to skip that rule only on npm packages but not on my app source. How can I configure for that?

Comment: Why are you setting noimplicity = true? Why do you need it set to true?

Comment: I find setting several of the Typescript compiler options helps produce better quality code including other flags like noImplicitReturns and noUnusedParameters. Ignoring `node_modules` seems to be the correct fix.

Answer (score 7):

You can skip type checking for all declaration files with `skipLibCheck` compiler option ([added in typescript 2.0](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#new---skiplibcheck))

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does this include node_module packages or just Type definition files?

Comment: @Rodney, _*.d.ts_ files (location doesn't matter). More info [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#new---skiplibcheck)