# How to properly check for unused variables/parameters in typescript applications

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, tslint

I want to check for unused variables/parameters in `Angular2` app generated by `Angular CLI 1.0.0-rc.1`.

1) I have added `"no-unused-variable"` rule for TSLint, but it says that:

> no-unused-variable is deprecated. Use the tsc compiler options
>   --noUnusedParameters and --noUnusedLocals instead.

2) I have added this options to compiler, but get a new issue with some third party packages:

> ERROR in .../node_modules/angular2-material-datepicker/src/datepicker.component.ts (3,43): 'state' is declared but never used.)
>   .../node_modules/angular2-material-datepicker/src/datepicker.component.ts (312,23): Property 'renderer' is declared but never used.)
>   .../node_modules/angular2-material-datepicker/src/datepicker.component.ts (386,20): 'day' is declared but never used.)

3) I have tried to add exclude options to TS config file in this way:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  },
  "exclude": [
    ...
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

But it didn't help, TS compiler shows warnings anyway.

Should the TS compiler check packages from node_modules?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40838654/2398593

Comment: @Maxime, *--skipLibCheck* doesn't help :( It only skip .d.ts files - [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

Answer (score 1):

you can use `--skipLibCheck` to skip checks on external libraries

Comment: *--skipLibCheck* doesn't help :( It only skip .d.ts files - [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).